# MySQL Query Optimization using multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble optimizing a query and could use some help. I'm currently pulling in events in a system that has to join several other tables to make sure the event is supposed to display, etc... The query was running smoothly (around 480ms) until I introduced another table in the mix. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    keyword_terms, 
    `esf`.*, 
    `venue`.`name` AS venue_name, 
    ...
    `venue`.`zip`, ase.region_id, 
    (DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN...AND ase.region_id IS NULL) as featured, 
    getDistance(`venue`.`lat`, `venue`.`lng`, 36.073, -79.7903) as distance, 
    `network_exclusion`.`id` as net_exc_id
FROM (`event_search_flat` esf)
# Problematic part of query (pulling in the very next date for the event)
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT event_id, MIN(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(event_date.date, ' ', event_date.end_time))) AS next_date FROM event_date WHERE 
        event_date.date >= CURDATE() OR (event_date.date = CURDATE() AND TIME(event_date.end_time) >= TIME(NOW()))
        GROUP BY event_id
) edate ON edate.event_id=esf.object_id
# Pull in associated ad space
LEFT JOIN `ad_space` ads ON `ads`.`data_type`=`esf`.`data_type` AND ads.object_id=esf.object_id
# and make sure it is featured within region
LEFT JOIN `ad_space_exclusion` ase ON ase.ad_space_id=ads.id AND region_id =5
# Get venue details
LEFT JOIN `venue` ON `esf`.`venue_id`=`venue`.`id`
# Make sure this event should be listed
LEFT JOIN `network_exclusion` ON network_exclusion.data_type=esf.data_type  
                 AND network_exclusion.object_id=esf.object_id
                 AND network_exclusion.region_id=5
WHERE `esf`.`event_type` IN ('things to do') 
AND (`edate`.`next_date` >= '2013-07-18 16:23:53')
GROUP BY `esf`.`esf_id`
HAVING `net_exc_id` IS NULL
AND `distance` <= 40
ORDER BY DATE(edate.next_date) asc, 
`distance` asc
LIMIT 6
```

It seems that the issue lies with the event_date table, but I'm unsure how to optimize this query (I tried various views, indexes, etc... to no avail). I ran EXPLAIN and received the following: http://cl.ly/image/3r3u1o0n2A46 . 
[image]

At the moment, the query is taking 6.6 seconds. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What all do you need from the `event_date` table?  Only the `min(timestamp` portion of your query?  Is that a distinct item per row, or can there be multiples?

Comment: Adding indexes on `esf`, `ads`, `ase`, and `network_exclusion` should help significantly.

Comment: event_date contains every date for each event. I only need the next_date (i.e. The MIN(date) that is greater than right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may be able to get `Using index` on the event_date subquery by creating a compound index over `(event_id, date, end_time)`.  That may turn the subquery into an index-only query, which should speed it up slightly.

  The subquery might be better written as the following, without `GROUP BY`:

  ```
  SELECT event_id, TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(event_date.date, ' ', event_date.end_time))) AS next_date
  FROM event_date 
  WHERE event_date.date >= CURDATE() 
    OR (event_date.date = CURDATE() AND TIME(event_date.end_time) >= TIME(NOW()))
  ORDER BY next_date LIMIT 1
  ```
- I'm more concerned that your EXPLAIN shows so many tables with **type=ALL**.  That means it has to read *every* row from those tables and compare to them rows in other tables.  You can get an idea of how much work it's doing by multiplying the values in the **rows** column.  Basically, it's making billions of row comparisons to resolve the joins.  As the tables grow, this query will get a lot worse.
- Using `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` has a specific purpose, and if you really mean to use `INNER JOIN` you should do that, because using an outer join where it doesn't belong can mess up the optimization.  Use an outer join like `A LEFT JOIN B` only if you want rows in `A` that may not have matching rows in `B`.

  For example, I assume based on column naming convention that `LEFT JOIN venue ON esf.venue_id=venue.id` should be an inner join, because there should always be a venue referenced by esf.venue_id (unless esf.venue_id is sometimes null).
- `event_search_flat` should have a compound index with columns used in the WHERE clause first, then columns to join to other tables:  `(event_type, object_id, data_type, event_id)`
- `ad_space` should have a compound index for the join: `(data_type, object_id)`.  Does this need to be an inner join too?
- `ad_space_exclusion` should have a compound index for the join: `(ad_space_id, region_id)`
- `network_exclusion` should have a compound index for the join: `(data_type, object_id, region_id)`
- `venue` is okay because it's doing a primary key lookup already.

Comment: Bill, just a quick read over your comments and I'm already encouraged. Your advice looks most excellent. Will implement your suggestions soon and heck, maybe even pick up a copy of your book.

Comment: Thanks for considering my book.  So were these suggestions successful?